# Guardar en archivo de salida .txt

Tags: php

tengo un código que me lee un fichero y me hace una serie de funciones al mismo. No sé muy bien como podría guardar el fichero una vez realizadas sus modificaciones en un archivo.txt. Podéis orientarme?
Aquí os dejo mi código

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");

$linea = fgets($fp);
echo $linea;


echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';

$texto = " <b><font size=\"4\"> <span style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>PALABRAS</span><font size=\"6\"></b> ";
echo $texto;
echo  '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo str_word_count(file_get_contents("archivo.txt"));

echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';


$texto = " <b></b> <font size=\"4\"> <span style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>NUEVO TEXTO</span>";

echo $texto;

echo '<br>';

echo '<br>';

echo eliminarVocales($linea);

function eliminarVocales($frase) {
  $vocales = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "I", "O", "U");
  return str_replace($vocales, "", $frase);

}
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar recomiendo que leas los permisos que le puedes pasar a fopen
http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php

Como puedes ver tú solo le estas pasando permisos de lectura, por lo que no puedes modificar el archivo, para pasarle permisos de escritura tienes que usar `rw` o `w+`

Después tendrías que almacenar el texto en una variable que sería el nuevo texto, así que en lugar de hacer los echos tendrías que almacenarlos en una variable

para terminar solo tendrías que usar `fwrite` (Documentación de fwrite : http://php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php)

Tu código quedaría así

```
 <?php
    $fp = fopen("archivo.txt", "rw");

    $linea = fgets($fp);
    echo $linea;


    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

    $texto = " <b><font size=\"4\"> <span style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>PALABRAS</span><font size=\"6\"></b> ";
    echo $texto;
    echo  '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo str_word_count(file_get_contents("archivo.txt"));

    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';


    $texto = " <b></b> <font size=\"4\"> <span style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>NUEVO TEXTO</span>";

    echo $texto;

    echo '<br>';

    echo '<br>';

    $fileText =  eliminarVocales($linea);
    echo $fileText;

    fwrite($fp, $fileText);
    fclose($fp);

     function eliminarVocales($frase) {
      $vocales = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "I", "O", "U");
      return str_replace($vocales, "", $frase);

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Pero ese código no hace nada diferente al que he pasado. Yo lo que quiero es que lo lea, haga las modificaciones pertinentes y lo guarde en otro archivo .txt ya con la modificaciones realizadas sobre el original.

Comment: entonces solo el `handle` a apuntando diferente, ese código guarda, lee la documentación de fwrite que te he puesto

Comment: no tiendo lo que quieres decir